# Automating the CLR profiling i.e. Automating CLR profiler memory dump mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, clrprofiler

I want to profile one of the application for memory leaks, the application is built up upon compact framework 3.5. I want to use CLR profiler which comes with Power tools set. Basically, I want to take memory snapshot every half hour for 2-3 days.

Does anybody has idea about how this can be done?

Thanks,
Omky